# blackberry - How to retrieve a unique identifier for a device?

Tags: blackberry, uniqueidentifier, udid

I am a blackberry development newbie. I want to find out a unique identifier tied to a blackberry device.

Is there one? If there is, how would I retrieve it programmatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're looking for is a [Blackberry PIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlackBerry#BlackBerry_PIN) and you can retrieve it using the static method [DeviceInfo.getDeviceID](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/DeviceInfo.html#getDeviceId%28%29).

> BlackBerry PIN is an eight character hexadecimal identification number
>   assigned to each BlackBerry device. PINs cannot be changed manually on
>   the device (though BlackBerry technicians are able to reset or update
>   a PIN server-side), and are locked to each specific BlackBerry.
>   BlackBerrys can message each other using the PIN directly or by using
>   the BlackBerry Messenger application. BlackBerry PINs are tracked by
>   BlackBerry Enterprise Servers, and the BlackBerry Internet Service,
>   and are used to direct messages to a BlackBerry device. Emails and any
>   other messages, such as those from the BlackBerry Push Service, are
>   typically directed to a BlackBerry's PIN. The message can then be
>   routed by a RIM Network Operations Center, and sent to a carrier,
>   which will deliver the message the last mile to the device. Example
>   2732E6DB

Answer (score 1):

Use the code below....

```
int pin = DeviceInfo.getDeviceId();  
String pinNumber = Integer.toHexString(pin);
```

you can get more info of BlackBerry Device on link below......

http://blog.vimviv.com/blackberry/blackberry-device-information-api/